# Create and use a target for SCNCamera

Tags: camera, scenekit

I come from 3D software use, wherein most cameras have a target, which makes moving the camera and its view point much easier, generally speaking, then using a "free camera" that's not got a target.

How would this be done in Scene Kit?

e.g. my first thought was to use an SCNNode as a dummy sort of target, fixed in the world space, connected via a physics joint to the camera.

When wanting to pan the camera, release the dummy from its lock in world space. All other operations (rotate, dolly, roll) the camera moves around/to the fixed dummy. And moving the dummy causes the camera to track it.

Is there a better way? Or easier way? Or more sensible way?

Comment: Do you mean the camera orbiting around whichever object is in front of it? If yes I can explain how it works.

Comment: Hey @Confused, did you see my previous message?

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot about this, I think the "look at" solves this, maybe.